# Entity Framework Core 2.1 IdentityUser IdentityDbContext<> Getting IdentityUserLogin requires primary key to be defined

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1 and I have a class,

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
```

The User table is part of the 1 and same database. In the Entity User class, it is defined as

```
public class User : IdentityUser
```

When I run and call `userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username)`,I get following error:

> IdentityUser IdentityDbContext<> Getting IdentityUserLogin requires primary key to be defined.

I googled and read someone's article on a possible solution. He said to use the following constructor

```
public DXContext(): base("name=DXContext")
{
     Database.SetInitializer<DXContext>(null);// Remove default initializer
     Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
     Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

In my constructor, I am passing the connector string as follow

```
public MyDbContext()
{
}

// context being added and passing to connection string to use
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<ASLDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
   // Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);            
}
```

I get a build error on SetInitializer method as follows:

> DatabaseFacade does not contain the definition for SetInitializer.

Any help will be appreciated to resolve the `IdentityUserLogin` primary key issue.

Comment: Share your full `MyDbContext` and `User` clases! Why did you share partial codes? Sometimes issue lies in the codes that you didn't share.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `startup.cs` user `AddDefaultIdentity<User>()` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Your `DbContext` can as simple as this

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Your extended user class

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string SomeAdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

`_LoginPartial.cshtml` Change the `IdentityUser` to your `User` class.

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
```

These 4 changes is all that is needed to get Identity working with an extended class (`User`) over the base `IdentityUser` when starting from a brand new project with authentication built-in.